# Does running under local IIS limit the number of Signalr connections

Tags: iis, signalr

I am testing my MVC Web App.

It uses SignalR.

I am running it under my local IIS

To test my web client I navigate to my page in a Chrome browser and open the same web page in different tabs.

The max number I can open is 2 tabs.

If I now close one of these tabs and open the same page on a different PC it will not open. I am using safari browser on this other PC.

If will connect if I close the other browser down on my 1st PC.

Yet, if I run the same code on my hosted server I can have many may client connections.

Is the a limit to the amount of client connections I can have running under my local IIS server or is there a setting I need to make somewhere?

Thanks

PS I could post relevant code but I do not think the code is the issue. I think it has to be the configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hit two limits - limits on the server side and limits on the browser side. Here is a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit) containing limits on the server side. As you can see the limit depends on the OS version and IIS version. You can find browser limits in this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser). Note that the client can open more than one concurrent requests (e.g. in case of long polling a poll request is almost always active and data is sent on a separate request).

Comment: Well if you for instance are running Windows 8 (Basic edition) the blog says the limit is 3 connections. Since SignalR may use 2 per a tab (e.g. single SignalR connection) it is not able to create another 2 for the second tab. Turn on tracing and take a look - it might give you some insight into what's really happening.

Comment: Actually this is the answer. I am using windows home basic